# Dynamic Web Project Tomcat NoClassFound Exception

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am learning J2EE programming, and follow this tutorial:
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/SchoolSchedule/BuildingAScheduleWebApp.html

I can run the simple jsp file(without Form submit) by tomcat. Below is the appearance of the jsp file:

[image: JSP Appearance]

However, if I added the servlet class to capture the Form submit action(thus add course), it reports error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.wtp.sample.classschedule.ScheduleServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
```

Below is the view of my project:

[image: project layout]

Below is my web.xml file:

[image]

Also the WRC file of my project is attached in this link: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1EhxQ7GBJdsU2dnbEZxVVBRZVU/edit?usp=sharing
You can import this project and debug in your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So where are the .class files?  Did you package and deploy them to Tomcat?

I'm betting you didn't create .class or WAR files.

Comment: I think your answer is correct...But how to create .class files? sorry to ask that, I am new to J2EE...

Comment: You need to compile the .java source into .class files.  Then you need to package those and all the other stuff that your web app needs into a WAR file that Tomcat can deploy.  Have a look at Eclipse build and package features.